# Unable to add artifact using WSO2 governance REST API into governance registry, as it is throwing exception. Can somebody help to resolve this issue?

Tags: java, wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

I am trying to add the artifact through SOAP UI withstandard JSON format mentioned in WSO2 Greg documentation:

Below is the exception :

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager} -  Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 34d84d58-9102-48db-903a-932d7a0141f8, path: /trunk/restservices/1.0.0/R1_Demo2. An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager}
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.get(HandlerManager.java:2466)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.get(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:910)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:512)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.utils.CommonUtil.getDefaultLifecycle(CommonUtil.java:794)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.utils.RESTServiceUtils.addServiceToRegistry(RESTServiceUtils.java:406)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.RESTServiceMediaTypeHandler.put(RESTServiceMediaTypeHandler.java:198)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:957)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:697)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:591)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:828)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:61)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:804)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:801)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:801)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.addGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:208)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic.GenericArtifactManager.addGenericArtifact(GenericArtifactManager.java:218)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.governance.rest.api.Asset.createGovernanceAsset(Asset.java:505)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.governance.rest.api.Asset.createAsset(Asset.java:172)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)

Comment: what is the API you are trying to access? We need more information related to G-Reg version and screen-shot of your request would help us a lot to provide a good answer.